# Can't export large data from oracle to excel file using c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a problem with extracting large data from oracle table to C#, and I
 couldn't find the solution myself.

For this task I wrote a C# code, which loaded data from oracle procedure, which returns cursor, in excel file for the first time.
But when I tried to load bigger table (about 20 columns and 90 000 rows), it just didn't work. 
Script doesn't fall with error, but data are not inserted into excel file.

I tried to load for 10 000 rows and then save the results, but again, only 30 000 rows were inserted.
I monitored the counter in loop, it is going correct and reach needed 90 000 and `ExecuteNonQuery()` always returned the value 10 000. But when I open excel file, there are only 30 000 rows there.

Can you please help me to catch the error, or may be somebody met the same problem,  and can advise me what to do or what to read.

Thank you for any help!

I didn't write the connection string, but I think, it's correct, cause script works correctly with small datatable.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();

        string qwe_constr = "connection string";
        OracleConnection myADONETConnection = new OracleConnection(qwe_constr);

        string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + "E:\\qaz\\15.07.2016\\qwe" +
                            ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

        File.Delete("E:\\qaz\\15.07.2016\\qwe.xlsx");

        //fill datatable with data for insert
        myADONETConnection.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd_proc = new OracleCommand();
        cmd_proc.Connection = myADONETConnection;
        cmd_proc.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd_proc.CommandText = "procedure_name";
        cmd_proc.Parameters.Add("p_show_del", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 0;
        cmd_proc.Parameters.Add("p_type", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 3).Value = "INV";
        cmd_proc.Parameters.Add("p_errno", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 157;
        cmd_proc.Parameters.Add("outcur", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        DataTable dt_with_data = new DataTable();
        dt_with_data.Load(cmd_proc.ExecuteReader());
        myADONETConnection.Close();

        //string with column headers
        string TableColumns = "";
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt_with_data.Columns)
        {
            TableColumns += column + "],[";
        }

        // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
        TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
        TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);

        //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
        Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
        Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
        Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
        Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table [sheet1] (" + TableColumns + ")";
        Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Excel_OLE_Con.Close();

        //Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
        //string with command
        Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
        String sqlCommandInsert = "";
        String sqlCommandValue = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dt_with_data.Columns)
        {
            sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
        }

        sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
        sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
        sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into [sheet1] (" + sqlCommandValue + ") VALUES(";

        int columnCount = dt_with_data.Columns.Count;

        int i_qaz = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt_with_data.Rows)
        {
            i_qaz++;
            Console.WriteLine(i_qaz.ToString());
            string columnvalues = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                int index = dt_with_data.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                columnvalues += "'" + dt_with_data.Rows[index].ItemArray[i].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "',";
            }
            columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
            var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // Create Log File for Errors
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("E:\\qaz\\15.07.2016\\qwe_" + datetime + ".log"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564568/c-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-excel-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-oledbcommand-executenonquery)

Comment: The problem is definetly with Excel provider. Please, check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/961fa23c-fc03-4cae-a9e4-7c0e7910804b/export-of-more-than-20000-rows-to-excel-xlsx-creates-empty-file?forum=adodotnetdataproviders It can be solution for you.

Comment: Build an intermediate container first, to eliminate any "contribution" from the Excel provider and see if your array or map is populated correctly.

Comment: Thank you for some ideas, i'll try to export my data to txt file today, in order to make sure on 100% that the problem with excel.

I didn't the solution on link above, but i ll try to exmine one more time today in details.

One more note. I changed my code and tried to update the value of every single cell, instead of using insert into sheet command, which inserts rows from datatable to excel file.

This way i could load even 100 000 rows and didnt get any error, but of course it took much more time, about 70 mins, when previous version inserted 30 000 rows in 2 mins.

Comment: So i'll continue trying to solve my problem, using 'insert into sheet values' command.

Thank you for help!            
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            int index = dt_with_data.Rows.IndexOf(row);
            columnvalues += "'" +                  dt_with_data.Rows[index].ItemArray[i].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "',";
        }

Comment: I use a NuGet package called ClosedXML which is actually really awesome.  It is easy to use and contains additional features to using a data connection (like setting autofilter, etc)